# Where can I view my PFUser objects in the Parse Data Browser?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, authentication

I'm getting to know Parse and am already having a tough problem.

I'm working with the User Login flow.  I need to be able to delete the User object I've just created.  Problem is, on the Dashboard, I only have the `Installation` data table.

I realized I wasn't explicitly saving this user object, although locally (on iOS) I could log in with the `currentUser` object credentials.  So I thought I'd remove the install from the simulator and try again (hey, since my data wasn't on the dashboard.)

Now I tried re-installing the app, using the same username/pass, and Parse SDK is telling me these are already taken!

So the question is, where is this User, and how do I completely remove the data so I can start over again?

```
2015-10-15 16:37:29.999 ParseApp[21428:2003831] [Error]: username myUserName already taken (Code: 202, Version: 1.8.5)
```

Comment: maybe you can enter parse.com website, and then you open your app on dashboard, probably you see your User on the left side name is User, and u remove user, who ever you want,

Comment: As I said, I don't see a PFUser table anywhere, just Installation.  Plus, I never saved the initial user that signed up with that user/pass, but now it won't let me sign up and save it.  I want to make sure i can sign up again with that username/pass

Comment: Whenever I've had a user class, I've seen it along with all the others on the lefthand pane.  Can you post an image?

Comment: Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdq1yn8kckodrtf/Screenshot%202015-10-15%2017.17.09.png?dl=0

Note, I'm doing this in the simulator, so I don't know if `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` is supposed to get called.  That's where I save the installation.  Anyway, the user table is not there.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem, but is kind of like a workaround for testing purposes.  I made a method:

```
- (IBAction)pressedDeleteSelf:(id)sender
{
    [[PFUser currentUser] deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (succeeded) {
            [PFUser logOut];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindSignedOut" sender:self];
        }
    }];
}
```

Which then allows me to re-create a user with the same credentials.  I still have no idea why the PFUser table does not show up in the Dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

Oh myyy... how silly do I feel.  With all these different tutorials I've been running, apparently I had been doing all this stuff using the wrong AppID and Client Key.  A rookie mistake, but hopefully someone else doesn't have to trip on this.

To be clear, solution is to make sure your App ID and Client key in the Parse dashboard match what you call in code:

```
// Initialize Parse.
    [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APP_ID
                  clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];
```

Embarrassed...